# Elasticsearch: Unable to save text with length over 800k

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to migrate from MySQL to Elasticsearch. One of field has Text length more than 800k in MySQL.
My properties:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/book' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "case": {
      "properties": {
        "lesson_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "lesson_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        },
        "lesson": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I am getting blank response when I run migrate script for the record.

Comment: 800K characters ? String fields longer than 32kb cannot be indexed

Comment: Thank you @eliasah , please suggest alternate solution

Comment: The only possibility for now is to truncate the text with the ignore_above parameter. Elasticsearch isn't fit for long text processing.

Comment: On the other hand, you might want to partition your text into multiple documents but then it's also a pb for designing search queries among the same text doc

Comment: @eliasah yes it would be a problematic

Comment: So there is actually no simple solution to your pb. None that can fit in a SO answer